# MouseEntered and MouseExited not working

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton, mouselistener

I am having trouble with mouseExited and mouseEntered events. They are not executed. And I know it is because of the `setLayout`. If I comment it, the problem dissapears.This is my code :

```
 public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new Pane());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public class Pane extends JPanel{
        public Pane(){
            ImageIcon start = new ImageIcon("Start.png");
            JLabel bStart = new JLabel(start);
            ImageIcon exit = new ImageIcon("Exit.png");
            JLabel bExit = new JLabel(exit);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            add(bStart, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            bStart.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Start-Pressed.png");
                    bStart.setIcon(image);
                    Container parent = bStart.getParent();
                    parent.remove(bStart);
                    add(bExit);
                    parent.revalidate();
                    parent.repaint();
                }

                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Start-Hover.png");
                    bStart.setIcon(image);
                }


                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Start.png");
                    bStart.setIcon(image);
                }
            });
            bExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
                  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
                      System.exit(0); 
                    } 

                  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
                      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Exit-Hover.png");
                      bExit.setIcon(image);

                  }
                  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
                      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Exit.png");
                      bExit.setIcon(image);
                  }
             }); 
        }    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your best bet for quick decent help is to create a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), one that uses readily accessible online images, one that is very short but that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: One unrelated suggestion: don't keep reading in your images in the listener code. Read the images in **once**, convert to ImageIcons and store in variable.s

Comment: I edited my original post.

Answer (score 2):

> And i know it is because of the setLayout. If i comment it, the problem dissapears.

I doubt the layout is the problem. If the component appears, then the layout manager has nothing to do with how MouseEvents are generated.

From you code is looks like you are trying to provide rollover effects. Instead of using a JLabel for this you can use a `JButton` and set Icons for the different rollover effects:

```
button.setBorderPainted( false );
button.setRolloverEnabled( true );
button.setRolloverIcon( ... );
button.setRolloverSelectedIcon(...);
button.setSelectedIcon(...);
```

Then there is no need to manage the MouseListener as the UI will do it for you.

To handle a mousePressed you should then be using an `ActionListener` on the JButton. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more information.

Comment: I don't want to use JButton because it has poor design .

Comment: @zaa: camickr knows what he's talking about. Give it a try.

Comment: I've tried it. This is the result : http://imgur.com/oUn4TU9   . Code:ImageIcon start = new ImageIcon("Start.png");
   ImageIcon roll = new ImageIcon("Start-Hover.png");
   ImageIcon select = new ImageIcon("Start-Pressed.png");
   
   JLabel bStart = new JLabel(start);
   ImageIcon exit = new ImageIcon("Exit.png");
   JLabel bExit = new JLabel(exit);
   JButton button = new JButton(start);
   button.setBorderPainted( false );
   button.setRolloverEnabled( true );
   button.setRolloverIcon(roll);
   button.setRolloverSelectedIcon(start);
   button.setSelectedIcon(select);
   add(button);

Comment: The problem are those margins(the ones from jbutton) around my green button .

Comment: I figured it out, but still, even with JButtons, if i setLayout() and add(button,BorderLayout.CENTER) the rollover and other options don't work, only without layout.

Comment: @zaa, if the component occupies the entire frame, then rollover events don't work, so don't use a layout manager that causes the component to take up all the space of the frame. The other option is to use an `EmptyBorder` on the JPanel so that there are other visible components on the frame.